# Reading Linked List from txt file (comma separated)

Tags: c++, file, io, linked-list

I was wondering what's the best way to read into a linked list from a text file?

I've currently got a write to file system working, however I'm unsure of how I can "reverse" it as such and populate my linked list?

He's my current write to file code:

```
void linkedList::writeFile()
{
    ofstream myfile;
    node* thisNode = head;
    myfile.open("example.txt");

    do
    {
        myfile << thisNode->shape<< ",";
        myfile << thisNode->colour << ",";
        myfile << thisNode->size << ",";
        myfile << thisNode->type << ",";
        myfile << thisNode->volume << ",";
        myfile << thisNode->density << ",";
        myfile << thisNode->capacity << ",";
        myfile << "\n";
        thisNode = thisNode->nextNode;
    } while (thisNode != NULL);

    myfile.close();
}
```

I'm open to all suggestions! :)

Thanks.

Comment: You need to use ifstream to read from file. Here are some good examples: http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/files/

Comment: Thanks for the link. I gathered that I was going to need a loop, however I'm still unsure about how I assign the node values from the getline command?

Comment: What if `head` is null at the start?

Comment: Can you elaborate Paul?

Comment: @GuestUser140561 Take this code `node* thisNode = head;` it assigns the value from the presumed member variable `head` to a local variable. Then goes on to use it without first checking if the value is null. So reading between the lines, if you call this function on an empty list then it will be undefined behaviour because it will dereference a null pointer here `thisNode->shape`. The solution is to use a while or for loop, rather than a do while.